# How to get the Id generated by the table while inserting data into the table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

This is the function which i wrote in DataAccess Layer, I am using WCF concepts also..
here i've to insert some values into RequisitionTable and i've to pass that Id returned from that table into another table..

In database table i specified RequisitionID column as primarykey and auto increment by 1.
in storedProcedure i declared RequisitionID as @RequisitionID int OUT

```
public RequisitionDTO createRequisition(RequisitionDTO requisitionDTO)
{

Logging.logDebug("RequisitionDA: createRequisition initiated");
DataTable requisitionDataTable = new DataTable();
try
{
  Database dataBase = CommonDB.getApplicationDatabase();
  //Insert and Store Id into variable 'i'  
  int i= dataBase.ExecuteNonQuery("SP_requisitionInsert",
     requisitionDTO.FirstName, requisitionDTO.MiddleName,    
     requisitionDTO.LastName,requisitionDTO.Address);
  int RequisitionID = Convert.ToInt16(i);

}
catch(exception e)
{
  //
}
```

Comment: int i= dataBase,ExecuteNonQuery(...);
  int RequisitionID = Convert.ToInt16(i); what do you think this code is supposed to do ? :o

Comment: What data access layer are you using? It's highly likely that the return value of `ExecuteNonQuery` is either the count of rows affected, or the return value of the stored procedure, neither of which is the value of the `@RequisitionID` parameter when the stored procedure completes.

Comment: I'm using SQL server 2005.. and in the end of the stored procedure i ve used the " set @RequisitionID=@@Identity" also,.. Why the storedProcedure s not retuning RequisitionID..

Comment: then the stored proc side of things is approximately correct (but as others have posted, you should prefer to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `@@IDENTITY` - you can google for the reasons why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing this is the Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block.

I can't find `Database.ExecuteNonQuery` documentation online, but from my offline help:

> Executes the *storedProcedureName* using the given *parameterValues* and **returns the number of rows affected**

(Italics in original, bold added by me)

I think you need to use one of the other overloads where you explicitly provide a command object, to which you've attached explicit parameter objects, including a parameter `@RequisitionID` set to output.

<strike>That's assuming your SP is correctly assigning `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to this parameter before returning, as others have suggested.</strike>

---

I've also found an article entitled [Executing a Command and Accessing Output Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664454%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx), which was written as part of the online docs for Enterprise Library, but you'll notice that unlike other parts of MSDN, it doesn't link to documentation for the individual methods, nor is there a "reference" part of the Enterprise Library - it's almost like they don't want people to find their documentation.

Answer (score 2):

If database engine is SQL SERVER, then [SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) returns the last identity value inserted into the table:

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql server 2005 or 2008 use [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) in your stored procedure